# Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple jpa based spring boot project

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "de.dahilein.resourcecal.repos")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ResourceCalApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceCalApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("resourcecal");
    return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I get the following stack trace

```
01:16:50.072 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Without it I get:

My datasource is jndi, name is set in persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="resourcecal" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/resourcecalDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

And the DS is defined in server.xml and linked to context.xml using a ResourceLink. This all seems to work because if I remove the DS or change the jndi names to test it reacts accordingly.

I see various logs that it is picking up the persistence.xml

```
01:54:27.223 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: resourcecal
    persistence provider classname: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    classloader: null
```

and the jndi name.

What am I missing?

Comment: add `@bean public DataSource myDatasource()` some where in your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Did you finally solve it and how?  I encountered exactly the same issue, `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` doesn't work at all. It seems to me that `DataSouce` is still scanned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bean in your configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSource= new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    jndiDataSource.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = jndiDataSource.getDataSource("jdbc/resourcecalDS");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include one other detail: the application was already working but I wanted to try it with spring boot. Why do I need to add the DataSoyrce bean now? What effect does the exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration have? If I remove it I get the same or similar error...

Comment: And btw when I do this I now get the following error:Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/resourcecalDS"
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) [na:1.8.0]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) [na:1.8.0]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem, in my case i had used spring boot dependency version 1.4.0 and also tried latest one but i had changed that to

```
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
```

**"2.0.5"**..

So check it if you have done same mistake then re-correct to it.